# Landing at terminal 2E of CDG airport and need to catch a connecting at terminal 2F. Do i need visa?

Tags: visas

I am landing at terminal 2E of CDG airport and need to catch a connecting at terminal 2F at CDG airport. Will i be required to get a visa to make this transfer?
I'm coming from UK and going to Algiers? Pakistan Nationality and having UAE residency.

Comment: Where are you coming from, where are you going to and what is your citizenship?

Comment: I'm coming from UK and going to ALgiers - Pakistan Nationality and having UAE resident visa

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the linked question. The other is a general question about the Schengen area, while this is specifically about CDG 2E and 2F. Relevant to this question is the presence (or lack) of an airside connection between the two terminals, which is exactly what @dda addresses in the answer.

Comment: @A.R. There is an airside connection between the terminals, but OP needs an ATV to transit through Paris due to their citizenship anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are from a country whose citizens do not need an airside visa, you should be fine. There's a [direct path airside](https://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/transfer-terminal-2e/terminal-2e-to-terminal-2f/) between the two terminals.

Comment: To be clear. As OP is a Pakistani citizen, they need an Airport Transit Visa even if they stay airside, unless they fall in one of the exemptions. And that only if the two flights are on the same ticket, otherwise they need a full visa.